# Rename XLS Files Using a Cell Value - Removing White Spaces and Special Characters

Tags: python, regex, openpyxl

**Situation:**
I'm attempting to rename XLS files in a directory using a specific cell value from each file (i.e. Cell A4 contains "Name1", use A4 to create `Name1.xls`). There's a script I found that will work for my purposes.

**Problem I'm trying to solve:**
Every cell I'm attempting to use as the filename has spaces and special characters. Ideally, I'd like to remove all the special characters and white spaces, and use that as the value to name each file. I'm not very familiar with regex so I'm not sure if I should be modifying the  `fileNameCheck = re.compile('[^\w,\s-]')` part of the code, or modify first if not block...

See below code:

```
# Import required modules
import openpyxl
import os
import re
import shutil

# File path

filePath = 'C:\\Users\name\Documents\Python\folder'

# Cell containing new file name
cellForFileName = 'A3'

# Check to see if the file path exists
if os.path.exists(filePath):

    # Change the current working directory
    os.chdir(filePath)

    # Check if there are any files in the chosen directory
    if len(os.listdir(filePath)) == 0:

        print('There are no files to rename')

    else:

        # Renamed file count
        filesRenamed = 0

        # Process the files at the path
        for filename in os.listdir(filePath):

            # Check if the file is an Excel file, excluding temp files
            if filename.endswith('.xls.xlsx') and not filename.startswith('~'):

                try:

                    # Open the file and find the first sheet
                    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
                    worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0]

                    # Check if there is a value in the cell for the new file name
                    if worksheet[cellForFileName].value is not None:

                        # Check to see if the cell value is valid for a file name
                        fileNameCheck = re.compile('[^\w,\s-]')
                        if not fileNameCheck.search(worksheet[cellForFileName].value):

                            # Construct the new file name
                            newFileName = worksheet[cellForFileName].value + '.xlsx'

                            # Close the workbook
                            workbook.close()

                            # Rename the file
                            shutil.move(filename, newFileName)

                            # Output confirmation message
                            print('The file "' + filename + '" has been renamed to "'
                                  + newFileName + '".')

                            # Increment the count
                            filesRenamed += 1

                        else:

                            # Display a message saying the file could not be renamed
                            print('The file "' + filename + '" could not be renamed.')

                            # Close the workbook
                            workbook.close()

                    else:

                        # Display a message saying the file could not be renamed
                        print('The file "' + filename + '" could not be renamed.')

                        # Close the workbook
                        workbook.close()

                except PermissionError as e:

                    # Display a message saying the file could not be renamed
                    print('The file "' + filename + '" could not be renamed.')

        # Display a message regarding the number of files renamed
        if filesRenamed == 1:
            print(str(filesRenamed) + ' file has been renamed.')
        else:
            print(str(filesRenamed) + ' files have been renamed.')

else:

    # Display a message stating that the file path does not exist
    print('File path does not exist.')
```

Thanks in advance for any help, advice, tips you can provide!

Comment: What happens if you run the code? What is the specific problem? regex101.com is a great website for learning and testing regexes.

Comment: Hey Charlie, if I have the following name: Acme Inc. : Acme Sub Inc., the second `else` clause runs resulting in `"The file xyz could not be renamed"`. If I manually remove the spaces, and special characters, the code successfully executes. Ideally, I'd love to just have the text after the `:` character pull as file name but I figured I would start with trying to implement this first iteration (remove special characters and spaces).

Comment: Break the task down into chunks, especially finding the files to rename.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance on solving this Charlie, really appreciate it. My inclination is to "clean" the filename up in the `cellforfilename` line, pulling in that data object, scrubbing it, and then passing it through the code. Is that approach reasonable or are there better methods?

Answer (score 0):

I think `filename.endswith('.xls.xlsx')` would not work the way is expected, following the documentation of [str.endswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) you may use a `tuple` (`.endswith(('.xls','.xlsx'))`. ) to match both `.xls` and `.xlsx`, furthermore, if you are working with both types of files is better to know the original extension and match that suffix during rename operation since they are interpreted in distinct ways.

> ... information [...] stored is vastly different for both XLS and XLSX formats. XLS is based on BIFF (Binary Interchange File Format) and as such, the information is directly stored to a binary format. On the other hand, XLSX is based on the Office Open XML format, a file format that was derived from XML... [[1](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-xls-and-xlsx/)]

You may use `_, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)` to get only the extension part to use later on the rename operation.

To remove special characters and spaces, you may use `re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "", nameCell)`. If the string after the `:` is allowed to contain `only` special characters and spaces, make sure to test for an empty string before writing the file name.

```
...
...
    # Process the files at the path
    for filename in os.listdir(filePath):
        # get extension to use later on file rename
        _, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if filename.endswith(('.xls','.xlsx')) and not filename.startswith('~'):
            try:
                workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
                worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0]
                # get the text after the ":"
                nameCell = re.search(":(.+)", worksheet[cellForFileName].value).group(1)
                # or use str.split(":")[1], make sure the range exists
                workbook.close()

                if nameCell is not None:
                    # remove special characters and spaces
                    clearName = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "", nameCell)
                    newFileName = clearName + extension
                    shutil.move(filename, newFileName)
                    print('The file "' + filename + '" has been renamed to "'
                            + newFileName + '".')
                    filesRenamed += 1
                else:
                    print('The file "' + filename + '" could not be renamed.')

            except PermissionError as e:
            ...
    ...
    ...
```